# snowflake sql - lateral flatten function compare with sql server - Split_String()

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have task to compare the counts and see if it's > 0

snowflake sql below

```
select 'abc'
from tableA
where 
(SELECT count(T1.value) as val
from tableA,
    lateral flatten(input=>split(abc, ',')) T1
    INNER JOIN (select count(T2.value) as val from 
lateral flatten(input=>split('1,2', ','))) as T2 on T1.val = T2.val) > 0
```

here is the error msg

```
SQL compilation error: error line 7 at position 29 invalid identifier 'T2.VALUE'
```

Sql server comparison that works.

```
(select Count(T1.value) as [Count] from STRING_SPLIT(abc,',') AS T1
    INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT('9,10', ',') AS T2 on T1.value = T2.value))>0
```

Comment: Check your parenthesis once, their positioning may not be correct. - "lateral flatten(input=>split('1,2', ','))) as T2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to reposition like this -

```
select 'abc'
from tableA
where
(select count(*) from
(SELECT count(flat_tab_alias1.value) as val
from tableA,
lateral flatten(input=>split(abc, ',')) flat_tab_alias1
) as T1
INNER JOIN
(
select count(flat_tab_alias2.value) as val from
lateral flatten(input=>split('1,2', ',')) flat_tab_alias2
) as T2
on T1.val = T2.val) > 0;
```

| 'ABC' |
| --- |

```
0 Row(s) produced.
```

With following source table -

```
select * from tablea;
```

| ABC |
| --- |
| a,b,c,d,e,f,g |

Comment: I got an error "SQL compilation error: error line 12 at position 11 invalid identifier 'T1.VAL'"

Comment: I've edited the query.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. I still have to work around a bit to put this in where clause, hopefully this will give me some insight.

Answer (score 1):

You SQL has many problems, but given we have working T-SQL lets decode that.

```
(select Count(T1.value) as [Count] from STRING_SPLIT(abc,',') AS T1
    INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT('9,10', ',') AS T2 on T1.value = T2.value))>0
```

This code is splitting a string array, and joining it to a set of "known" values, and counting how mean are equal, and just asking if there is any overlap.

[ARRAY_OVERLAP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/arrays_overlap.html) answer this, and using SPLIT to make the arrays:

```
SELECT abc, 
    split(abc, ',') as a1,
    split('1,2', ',') as a2,
    ARRAYS_OVERLAP( a1, a2)
FROM values
    ('1'),
    ('0,4'),
    ('0,1,5')
    t(abc);
```

gives:

| ABC | A1 | A2 | ARRAYS_OVERLAP( A1, A2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [ "1" ] | [ "1", "2" ] | TRUE |
| 0,4 | [ "0", "4" ] | [ "1", "2" ] | FALSE |
| 0,1,5 | [ "0", "1", "5" ] | [ "1", "2" ] | TRUE |

So your SQL should be:

```
SELECT 'abc', abc
FROM tableA
WHERE ARRAYS_OVERLAP( split(abc,','), split('1,2',','));
```

which with the dummy data:

```
    select * from values
    ('1'),
    ('0,4'),
    ('0,1,5')
```

gives:

| 'ABC' | ABC |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 1 |
| abc | 0,1,5 |