# SQL to find related rows in Loop in ANSI SQL or Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where I need to link all related CUSTOMER ID and assign a Unified Cust ID to all the related Cust_id.
Ex: for below data,

```
INPUT DATA
PK_ID CUST_ID_1 CUST_ID_2   CUST_ID_3
1       123      456         567
2       898      567         780
3       999      780         111
4       111      222         333
```

Based on CUST_ID_1/CUST_ID_2/CUST_ID_3 need to link all the and assign a Unified ID to all the rows.

```
OUTPUT DATA
Unified ID  CUST_ID_1   CUST_ID_2   CUST_ID_3
1000    123 456 567
1000    898 567 780
1000    999 780 111
1000    111 222 333
```

Trying to perform Self Join but it cannot be definite. Is there a function or ANSI SQL feature which can help in this?

What i have tried,

```
CREATE TEMP TBL_TEMP AS(
SELECT A.PK_ID
FROM TBL A
LEFT JOIN TBL B
ON A.CUST_ID_1=B.CUST_ID_1
AND A.PK_ID<>B.PK_ID)

UPDATE TBL
FROM TBL_TEMP
SET UNIFIED_ID=SEQ_UNIF_ID.nextval
WHERE TBL.PK_ID=TBL_TEMP.PK_ID
```

This update i have to write for each column and multiple times.

Comment: What is the logic for unification? Also, include input data as text and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your attempt at doing this. Also, please don't use images to post code or data - please post it as text so other people can copy and use it in examples without having to retype everything. In addition, it's not clear what is common between all this data.

Comment: Is the common element to be searched only in next row only or can it be anywhere (any previous or subsequent row) in the table? For example if only looking in next row, then row-1 has 567 and row-2 has 567, hence common and assign same ID, next row 2 and 3 has 780 common, so assign same ID. Assume row 4 and 5 have nothing in common then assign a new ID (different then from row-4) to row 5, and continue like this..

Comment: Not just next row. It can be anywhere. If any column value matches with any row we need to assign same ID

Comment: So, effectively there will be just one big bunch of rows with a common id (say 1000) and rest all of the rows with different IDs. What I mean is the common ID will only be one for the entire table as we are finding common in the whole set any where which effectively means grouping all common under 1 ID.

Comment: Yes the Unified ID will link all the rows where any of the customer id matches with any of the customer id of any row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with gap in sequences then following is what I can come up with as of now.

```
update cust_temp a
set unified_id = t.unified_id
from
(
select
case
when (select count(*) from cust_temp b
where arrays_overlap(array_construct(a.cust_id_1,a.cust_id_2,a.cust_id_3),
array_construct(b.cust_id_1,b.cust_id_2,b.cust_id_3)))>1 -- match across data-set
then 1000 -- same value for common rows
else
ts.nextval --- using sequence for non-common rows
end unified_id,
a.cust_id_1,a.cust_id_2,a.cust_id_3
from cust_temp a, table(getnextval(SEQ_UNIF_ID)) ts) t
where t.cust_id_1 = a.cust_id_1
and t.cust_id_2 = a.cust_id_2
and t.cust_id_3 = a.cust_id_3;
```

Updated data-set

```
select * from cust_temp;
```

| UNIFIED_ID | CUST_ID_1 | CUST_ID_2 | CUST_ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 123 | 456 | 567 |
| 1000 | 898 | 567 | 780 |
| 1000 | 111 | 222 | 333 |
| 20000 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 1000 | 999 | 780 | 111 |
| 1000 | 234 | 123 | 901 |
| 23000 | 260 | 360 | 460 |
| 24000 | 160 | 560 | 760 |

Original data set -

```
select * from cust_temp;
```

| UNIFIED_ID | CUST_ID_1 | CUST_ID_2 | CUST_ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 123 | 456 | 567 |
| NULL | 898 | 567 | 780 |
| NULL | 111 | 222 | 333 |
| NULL | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| NULL | 999 | 780 | 111 |
| NULL | 234 | 123 | 901 |
| NULL | 260 | 360 | 460 |
| NULL | 160 | 560 | 760 |

Arrays_overlap [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277970/snowflake-sql-lateral-flatten-function-compare-with-sql-server-split-string) is thanks to @Simeon.

Following procedure can be used -

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  duplicate number;
  x number;
BEGIN

  duplicate := (select count(cnt) from (select a.unified_id,count(*) cnt from cust_temp a,
  cust_temp b
  where
  arrays_overlap(array_construct(a.cust_id_1,a.cust_id_2,a.cust_id_3),
array_construct(b.cust_id_1,b.cust_id_2,b.cust_id_3))
AND a.cust_id_1 != b.cust_id_1
AND a.cust_id_2 != b.cust_id_2
AND a.cust_id_3 != b.cust_id_3
group by a.unified_id) where cnt>1
);

for x in 1 to duplicate do
update cust_temp a
set a.unified_id = (select min(b.unified_id) uid from cust_temp b
where arrays_overlap(array_construct(a.cust_id_1,a.cust_id_2,a.cust_id_3),
array_construct(b.cust_id_1,b.cust_id_2,b.cust_id_3)));

end for;
END;
$$
;
```

Which will produce following output dataset -

| UNIFIED_ID | CUST_ID_1 | CUST_ID_2 | CUST_ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 2000 | 123 | 456 | 567 |
| 2000 | 898 | 567 | 780 |
| 2000 | 111 | 222 | 333 |
| 2000 | 999 | 780 | 111 |
| 2000 | 234 | 123 | 901 |
| 7000 | 260 | 360 | 460 |
| 8000 | 160 | 560 | 760 |
| 8000 | 186 | 160 | 766 |

For an input data-set as -

| UNIFIED_ID | CUST_ID_1 | CUST_ID_2 | CUST_ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 2000 | 123 | 456 | 567 |
| 3000 | 898 | 567 | 780 |
| 4000 | 111 | 222 | 333 |
| 5000 | 999 | 780 | 111 |
| 6000 | 234 | 123 | 901 |
| 7000 | 260 | 360 | 460 |
| 8000 | 160 | 560 | 760 |
| 9000 | 186 | 160 | 766 |

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. One question how can i use a sequencer in case of hardcoding value 1000. I tried using sequence but its generating different value. In the data set this works for 4 rows which were overlapping. But if the last two also overlap just with each other and not with the original 4 it will also assign them ID 1000.

Comment: For Example: 
`UNIFIED_ID CUST_ID_1 CUST_ID_2 CUST_ID_3
1000 123 456 567
1000 898 567 780
1000 111 222 333
20000 100 200 300
1000 999 780 111
1000 234 123 901
23000 160 360 460
23000 160 560 760`
Last two rows overlap just with each other so they should have a unique id

Comment: I think using recursive WITH clause would help me.. I tried out if there were 2 columns to match. It is working. But in case of 3 columns it's becoming complex. Referenced: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IK-oyADbTYE  for 2 column relationships. Figuring out for 3 columns relationships

Comment: Sure, try and post back in case you get something.